# Gnuplot - custom values for certain Y ticks, keep the "distance" equal

Tags: gnuplot

I need to draw a chart that has some number of "extreme" Y outbreaks (like most of the data is within the range 0-100, and some values are 10000+).

Is there any way to have some progressive scale of ticks while keeping the distance in between of ticks equal, for example

```
10000 -
      |
      |
   400-
      |
      |
   100-
      |
      |
    50-
      |
      |
    20-
      |
      |
    10-
      |
      |
     5-
      |
      |
     0-
```

Comment: Maybe use logscale?

Comment: This question has already been answered for 3D plot. The idea is the same: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33377827/customize-color-ranges-in-gnuplot/33384336#33384336